# Can Web Worker `importScripts` method access scripts cached by the main thread?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, web-worker

Multiple questions actually:

- Will `importScripts` always load the scripts with a GET request or can it cache scripts?
- Can `importScripts` access scripts cached in the main thread or browser context?
- Can the worker cache scripts for the main thread to access? (simply the other way around)

Answer (score 1):

1. importScripts will not load the script again if you specify http cache headers like 'Expires' or 'Cache-control' properly, see [google recomendations](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching) about that
2. There is a kind of 'gateway filter' between threads, that allows primitives like booleans, strings to go through but not objects/functions. If you load your script via XHR as a string in main thread, you'll probably be able to send it to the worker thread and eval there.
3. See the answer #1

Comment: This does not seem to be true. I have a bunch of PHP served Javascript with proper cache directives. Caching works fine, but never with importScripts. The linked Google page just describes the status quo.